# Continuous momentum space

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory

In quantum mechanics/quantum field theory when you have a continous position space that is bounded, you obtain a discrete mometum space, this comes by writing your boundary conditions generally $\psi(x=0)=\psi(x=L)$.

Since position and momentum are conjugates, if you have an infinite but discrete position space, you should get a continous k space (but bounded??). I see the link with Fourier transform, but I was wondering how the boundary conditions would "translate" in this example.

Comment: Are you aware of the fourier transform of the sine/cosine function? The sine/cosine is not integrable through the entire space using classical integration methods, you have to approach it from distribution viewpoint and you will find out that the result is delta-function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A periodic momentum space is basically what Brillouin zones are all about. When there are only discrete points $x=na$, with $n\in {\mathbb Z}$ and $a$ is the  lattice spacing, the function 
$e^{ikx}$ takes the same values at any $x=na$ for both  $k$ and $k+2\pi/a$. Consequently  $k$ and $k+2\pi/a$ are equivalent. They are said to be related by a *reciprocal lattice vector*.